# Javascript variable doesn't will exist outside?

Tags: javascript

short and sweet, I'm trying to apply the variable "eld" outside of the script so that I can apply it to the whole page or on another page via include anyone know how I can do it?
(document.write (exp1, exp2, exp3, ...))

```
$(window).load(function(){
var mapname = "de_dolls";
var eld;

$.get("backgrounds/" + mapname + "/1.jpg")
    .done(function () {
        eld = mapname;
    }).fail(function () {
        eld = "default";    
});
document.write ( eld );
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: This is a duplicate of about 10 000 different SO threads...

Comment: who have the time to find exactly the same thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous. The function won't have finished when you try to display it. Also `document.write` is not considered good coding practice. If you do this, using a callback, you'll get a better result:

```
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```

```
function getBackgrounds(mapname, callback) {
  $.get("backgrounds/" + mapname + "/1.jpg")
   .done(function () {
     callback(mapname);
  })
   .fail(function () {
     callback('default');
  });
}

getBackgrounds('de_dolls', function (response) {
  $('#thisdiv').html(response);
});
```